# Postgres IN clause on a two column unique constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a unique constraint across two columns, `code` and `print`, and an array of codes and prints. See below:

```js
// these two arrays can get very big
codes: ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') 
prints: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Is there a way to get the rows with code A and print 1, code B and print 2, and so on, in one query? My initial thought was to use a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE code IN (...)` query, but I'm not quite sure how to correctly "map" the `print` to the correct `code`.

Please let me know if something doesn't make sense and I'll do my best to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM table AS t
 INNER JOIN unnest(array['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], array[1, 2, 3, 4]) AS a(code, print)
    ON t.code = a.code
   AND t.print = a.print
```

Every element in both arrays are coupled two by two in the `unnest()` function according to their order in their arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select the_table.* 
from the_table
join unnest ('{A,B,C,D}'::text[], '{1,2,3,4}'::int[]) as t(a, b)
on (code, print) = (t.a, t.b);
```